# Translate SQL Search Query to Eloquent Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I would like to have the following query.

```sql
select * from `items` 
    where (`item_name` LIKE 'foo' or `item_description` LIKE 'foo') 
    and `item_type` = 'type1'
```

Translated into Eloquent. I have come up with the following statement:

```php
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
    ->orWhere('item_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
    ->orWhere('item_description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
    ->sortable(['id' => 'desc'])
    ->paginate(10);
```

In the above snippet, `$q` will be `foo` (it's a search query).

The problem is that this does not return exactly what I want since it also returns items that belong to another `item_type` instead of the `type1` in my example.

How can I translate the above SQL query in an Eloquent query so that it only returns the items which contain `foo` and which are of type `Type1` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You need a nested `where` closure:

```
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
                ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
                    $query->where('item_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                          ->orWhere('item_description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
                })
           ->sortable(['id' => 'desc'])
           ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks sir, much appreciated! This works indeed. Could you provide some explanation on why the nested where closure is required?

Comment: what you had before is wrong, because orWhere("item_name", "LIKE") would come after where("item_type")  which means that if even one of these where's results exist, it fetches them. to further understand, this would be your query from your eloquent: "select * from items where "item_type"=type1 or where item_name LIKE $q.   in my answered post, it would be where "item_type"=type1 AND (where "item_name" LIKE $q or where "item_description LIKE $q)